# Do I have to over/underclock for mining?

Tags: mining, gpu

I have RX480 and RX580. Two GPUs together giving stable 23,4Mh each. 
I'm using linux so clocking them will require playing with bios which I'm bit afraid to do.

Can I run them like that, without any modification for a long period ? 
I prefer stability over high hashrate now.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hi those are somewhat lower hashrates than expected for RX480 and RX580. I can't advise regarding Linux, but on Windows with Claymore miner and WattTool you can both undervolt and get better hashrates, along with stability. On Windows you won't need to modify the BIOS unless you really want to (memory timing for Polaris).